# Memory heap increases while chrome tab is inactive running canvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, memory

I am struggling to resolve this memory issue for few days. There are lots of discussion regard HighCharts memory increasing while running in inactive tab. Also one option is rewrite some rendering function. However, I don't have the source code of this canvas. Although it will be possible by inspecting the page source code to read through.
I have also tried to disable hardware acceleration, but memory keep increasing if canvas running in inactive tab. Once I bring it to active, the memory decrease rapidly to normal.

My question: is there any quick solution to overwrite few canvas function to prevent rendering in background?

or change some setting of chrome to achieve this goal?

or workable solution to bring inactive tab to front in certain interval?

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the source code of the page from console, I found it is NOT canvas bug. There are some user functions using timeout logic to rendering the page which caused this memory issue. After overwritting such function, the page running for more than 20 hours without memory increase.

To summary, chrome or canvas most probably do NOT have this kind of memory issue, it is caused by the page script itself. Please inspecting the page source code to resolve it. Hope my practice can help you.

Comment: one more thing, I have also enabled hardware acceleration, the memory is stable without increasing.